# How to embed a video player in NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nsview

I want to embed a video player in an `NSView`. I also want to play different files, passing the path of these files. Is it possible to implement in a Mac application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For QTKit, the [QTKit Application Tutorial - Creating a Simple QTKit Media Player Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH3-SW8) takes you through the basic steps.

Comment: But in this method movie will be opened in new window right? I want to embed the player in my application windows NSView.

Comment: @Nix: They show how to utilize a `QTMovieView`, which you can put as a subview in your view as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the AVFoundation frameworks now in 10.7 - [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html) looks like a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was circling around QTKit framework.Now I will try this framework

Comment: It might be worthwhile tagging the question with osx-lion if you know you are targetting Lion onwards.

Comment: oops! I was looking for a framework which will work in Snow leopard